# React form field value not updating after setState changes it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-native, frontend

I have an issue I could use some help with.

I have a form that allows users to upload images. After an image is uploaded, the function returns the image URL as a string, which I save using `setState`. This string is passed into a form field as a value.

**✨✨THE ISSUE✨✨**

The URL string is received and updated successfully with setState after image is uploaded. I can verify this with console.log in the following images. However! Although the form shows the value of imageUrl has changed, after the user clicks submit, the form submits the ORIGINAL value, which is set to null. **How do I make it read the updated value of imageUrl?**

**Where imageUrl is initialized**

```
class SubmitForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      imageUrl: null,
    }

    this.onInputchange = this.onInputchange.bind(this);
  }

  onInputchange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    console.log("ONCHANGE CALLED")
  }
```

**Function that uploads image and does setState**

```
  openWidget = () => {
    // create the widget
    window.cloudinary.createUploadWidget(
      {
        cloudName: '[redacted for stack overflow]',
        uploadPreset: '[redacted for stack overflow]',
      },
      (error, { event, info }) => {
        if (event === 'success') {
          this.setState({
            imageUrl: info.secure_url,
          })
        }
      },
    ).open(); // open up the widget after creation
  };
```

**Code that sets the value in the form field**

```
  render() {
    const { imageUrl, imageAlt } = this.state;
    let fRef = null;
    console.log("FORM IS RENDERED")
    console.log("Curent value of imageUrl is ", imageUrl)


    return (
      <Grid container>
                    ...
                    <Button type="button" className="btn widget-btn" onClick={this.openWidget}>Upload Image</Button>
                    ...

                    <TextField name='imageUrl' value={this.state.imageUrl} onChange={this.onInputchange}/>
                    ...
                    ...

      </Grid>
    );
```

**Before an image is uploaded**

[image]

**After**

the onChange doesnt seem to have been called? It would console log if it did.

[image]

**Form submission**

The field is required, and it throws an error because its reading in the ORIGINAL value of imageURL (which is null). How do I make it read the updated value of imageUrl?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any form validation library like `react-hook-form` or `formik`?

Comment: If it reads the initial value of the state, you might want to rerender when state changes, by using useEffect: useEffect(() => change the state here, []);

Comment: Im using Uniforms.

Comment: The `TextField` is a controlled input, so state is certainly updating. What is happening when the "upload image" button is clicked? What is `openWidget` doing?

Comment: @DrewReese The "upload image" button activates openWidget, which allows users to drag and drop photos to upload. I edited to show the full code. If an image uploads successfully, a url to access the image is returned in `info.secure_url`

Comment: You are updating `this.state.imageUrl` in that `openWidget` handler, this isn't the text input changing anything. In other words, there's ZERO interaction with the text input, you are simply updating the rendered value. No input `onChange` event will fire. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" as this is, I believe, expected behavior.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for your answer!! I really do appreciate it. I did notice onChange wasnt firing at all.. What function should be used to update the text input?

Comment: Are you referring to normal updates, i.e. typing in the text field? The `onChange` should work for that. Is that not the case for your code, and if so, can you create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese The users are not allowed to modify the url manually, aka type in it. The field will actually be a hidden field, so it wont show on the page anyway. Working on creating a demo right now!

Comment: Ok, feel free to ping (@) me if/when it's available and I'll take a look. Though, if you don't expect a user to interact with it, and it will be hidden, is it even needed? It seems rather useless at that point.

Comment: @DrewReese Done! Took a second but here is the invite.  Couldnt get onChange to work for some reason but the rest works and bug is duplicated. https://codesandbox.io/live/54847d651fe Its required for a user to upload the image. When they do, I store the image url as part of their profile data in my database. Then I can display the image by retrieving the url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237666/discussion-between-arslan-and-drew-reese).